# PHP File Runs Fine Manually But behaves unexpected on Cron Job

Tags: php, cron

I have a dreamhost web panel and I am setting a cronjob to run my php script, but it shows weird errors, it looks like that it's not executing the file , but it's reading the file. The error is shown below, it comes as email to me

> ?php: No such file or directory [somesessionvariable]=1573: command
>   not found  line 3: syntax error near unexpected token
>   `"include/mydb.php"'  line 3:`require_once("include/mydb.php");

This is the subject of the mail:

> Cron  /usr/local/bin/setlock -n
>   /tmp/cronlock.3782446772.128284 sh -c $'/path /to/file/cases_cron.php'

the permission of the file is 755 and i have copied the path from other perfectly running cronjobs, so no issue to the file path as it's getting the file contents. I am not getting where the problem is

Comment: Looks like you have a single quote at the end of the `require_once();'`. Show the code.

Comment: I love questions starting with `I have a dream` ;). About the question: we might need some more details. Code, folder structure for example.

Comment: <?php
require_once dirname(__FILE__)."/include/mydb.php";
require_once dirname(__FILE__)."/include/all_common.php";
//include('../preloadsClients.php');
if(!$db) $db = new DB();
$qry="SELECT * FROM Cases WHERE Case_CaseId is NULL";
//echo $qry;
$db->query($qry);
if($db->rows()>0)
{ and rest of the code, But about the directory structure there is no issue as i have just copied these lines from the working scripts, that are working fine on the cron. But this is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, Guys, Thanks for all of your support, I am finally able to sort out the matter.

I was missing the following line on the top of the file

`#!/usr/local/bin/php`

Adding this line at the top of the php file, sorted my problem. But i don't know that what this line means to the script. But i copied it from other working crons.

Comment: the line is #!/usr/local/bin/php

Comment: It tells the OS what interpreter to use. Use `php -f <filename of script>` in your cron job instead. Will then get the same output if run by cron or on the command line (or by a web server for that matter)

Answer (score 1):

I should try to use an absolute path to your include file.

I'm sure the problem is about the include path not being set the same in file call and cron call.

You can do something like this :

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__)."/include/mydb.php";
```

`__FILE__` is the path of the file where this line is executed, `dirname()` return the absolute path where the file is located.

Of course, you can use, as you want `require`, `require_once`, `include`, `include_one`

Comment: FYI [since 5.3](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) `__DIR__` contains `dirname(__FILE__)`

Comment: thanks for the reply, but as i mentioned before that same include is working in other cron files

Comment: Thans @DaveRandom, I didn't knew it. @King Khan, it appears that the problem is about the `'` at the end of the include. Remove it and it will work.

Comment: no, there is no ' in the file, it's here in the reply mail, may be the cron has mentioned the error  like 'somethign'. But in the file there is no quote sign

Answer (score 0):

Your paths are probably off. Try to either avoid relative paths (include/file.php instead of /var/www/project/include/file.php) or change your working directory with [chdir()](http://se.php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php).

Answer (score 0):

You can also put an 'cd' command into your cronjob ie:

```
cd /path/to/phpfile && php -f file.php
```

Comment: thanks, but as i mentioned above that there is no path issue as the cron is accessing the file and showing the error in the file contents